# How to get a specific map out of a list of maps that has a bigger than or smaller than value than the rest?

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, dart, maps

I'm working on a app where I retrieve json data via http, and I have made the listview.builder and all of that. Now I want to make a filter button to show the lists that only have values below a certain integer.
for example:
my list of maps goes something like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "jess",
    "age": "28",
    "job": "doctor"
  },
  {
    "name": "jack",
    "age": "30",
    "job": "jobless"
  },
  {
    "name": "john",
    "age": "24",
    "job": "doctor"
  },
  {
    "name": "sara",
    "age": "23",
    "job": "teacher"
  }...etc
]
```

Now I want to press that filter button and in my listview show only those that are below or above the age of 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer and it was there all the time I just didn't thought about that much.
In case anyone faces the same issue, here's how it worked for me.

```
list filteredList = peopleDetailsList.where((element) => int.parse(element['age'] < 25).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over it and add your "filter" inside the condition. Since you save age as String you have to parse it to an int:

```
 var filteredList = myMapList.map((e){
    int? parsedAge = int.tryParse(e["age"]!);
    if(parsedAge != null && parsedAge >= 25){
      return e;
    }
   }).toList();
```

Comment: I tried your method and thank you it worked unfortunately on my app it caused a stack overflow error.